# MSSQL Search inside a JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i filter inside a json file in SQL server?

i have a Column call details.

```
{"test","source":"web"}
```

i want to filter by source

what i did:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(details,'$.source')
where value ='web'
```

Comment: You need a valid JSON to use OPENJSON. Your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

As per Zohar's comment, make your json valid, then something like:

```
--{"mode":"test","source":"web"}


select * from TABLE_NAME 
CROSS APPLY 
  OPENJSON(details)
  WITH (   
    m varchar(256) '$.mode',
    s varchar(256) '$.source'
  ) j
where
  j.w = 'web'
```

But it might suit you better/simpler to just use JSON_VALUE:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
WHERE json_value(details, '$.source') = 'web'
```

Use CROSS APPLY OPENJSON if you want to turn each row's json into a pseudotable looking like the table spec in the WITH clause. SQLServer behaves as if all the matching "rows" in each row's json are compounded into the psseudotable and auto-joined to the source data table based on where each bunch of json pseudorows came from

Use JSON_VALUE if you only really want one value out of the json and can uniquely identify a single "row" in the json from which to get the value.. Either the json only has one "row" / is not a collection, or you want a "row" out of a json collection that can be referenced according to a formula